# Generate non-debug apk from ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using ionic framework to generate apk for android platform.

After running `ionic build android`, an android-debug.apk is generated. How can I generate a non-debug apk which is smaller and faster?

Comment: Use the --release flag. cordova build --release android. http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is my android release shell script

IFY

```
clear

gulp

ionic build --release android

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore "path/to/your/keystore" "platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk" "keystore alias" -storepass xxx -keypass xxx 

/path/to/android-sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/zipalign -v 4 "platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk" "android-release.apk"

rm "platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk"
```

Answer (score 6):

**In cordova 6.2.0** you can release an apk with follwoing commands. Since ionic is a wrapper around cordova, this should work.

```
cd cordova/ #change to root cordova or ionic folder
platforms/android/cordova/clean #clean if you want
cordova build android --release -- --keystore="/path/to/keystore" --storePassword=password --alias=alias_name #password will be prompted if you have any
```

Answer (score 2):

As ionic CLI is based on cordova CLI, you can use, directly:

`ionic build android --release`

Also, if you are worried about optimization, you might find interesting usign **zipalign**, in order to align data on 4-byte boundaries, thus causing the app to reduce the amount of RAM used. Once you have build the release apk with the previous command, you can run:

`zipalign -v 4 yourReleaseApp.apk zipalignedReleaseApp.apk`

Answer (score 1):

Basically, as Jan commented, you should use the command: `cordova build android --release`. You can take a look at the official guide from Ionic about [how to publish your app](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html).

Answer (score 1):

**1.** To release build for Android, we can use the following cordova cli command

ionic cordova  build  --release android

**2.**  Build apk is unsigned. Need to sign it. That’s why create private key with keytool of JDK. we can use following cli command

keytool -genkey -v –keystore mykey.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

keep the mykey.keystore file in a safe place for future use.
if the keytool is not work then copy path of this file and set it in the system environment variable.

**3.** Now sign the unsigned apk with the following command

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore mykey.keystore projectpath\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk alias_name

**4.** At last optimize the apk file.

zipalign -v 4 projectpath\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk projectpath\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release.apk

for more details you can visit following url
[Build Release APK of Android Application from ionic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPd4T7NTxzM)