# Can't build Ionic/Cordova Android project using Gradle

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

I'm trying out ionic for the first time. I have no issues with iOS, but building the demo app for Android gives me an error with virtually no information (see below). It seems likely to me that the issue is with the gradle config file that ships with Cordova, but I don't believe it's considered good practice with Cordova to edit the platform-specific files if you can avoid it.

```
[myApp]Bro? ionic build android
Running command: /Users/x/Documents/Dev/myApp/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /Users/x/Documents/Dev/myApp
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: /Users/x/Documents/Dev/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/build 
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/x/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
Running: /Users/x/Documents/Dev/myApp/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/x/Documents/Dev/myApp/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
   > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
      > java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: you can follow the link [Build Release APK of Android Application from ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116446/generate-non-debug-apk-from-ionic/45866053#45866053)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked at the stacktrace and it was clear that I had an issue with my Java XPath and XQuery libraries (Saxon). Turns out I hadn't updated that library since migrating from JDK 7 to JDK 8, and JDK 8 is not compatible with the version I had installed. Looks like the Android build uses the same plugin to parse the AndroidManifest.xml.

Short answer - look at your stack trace. Perhaps it also has to do with an outdated Java library.

Comment: Note, after doing this I still have to run all cordova/ionic commands as sudo, but only for android.