# ionic build android : No APK file generated in Ionic 2

Tags: android, node.js, ionic2

I just executed the command "ionic build android" on my ionic 2 project and it was done successfully it says. But there is no APK file generated. What am I supposed to do? Thanks in advance. I'm using node v6.11.2, Ionic CLI 3.7.0, cordova 7.0.1.

Comment: The apk is normally generated in `yourProject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-release-unsigned.apk`. If it isn't there, please add in your output of the command

Comment: yes, but there is no /build folder inside my android folder.

Comment: Having the same issue

Comment: you can follow following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116446/generate-non-debug-apk-from-ionic/45866053#45866053

Comment: Thank you, I already solved the issue, I manually installed the gradle and set all the Environmental Variables properly.

Answer (score 0):

First create an account at ionic Io
than hit this ionic Io init in project directory 
after login hit this ionic package build android
after successful your apk file store in your cloud and download it and install

Comment: Include some images so it can help people understand the answer better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm sorry but what exactly I gonna do to get the APK file.

Comment: set all software(node.js,apache ANT,Java JDK & JRE,Android SDk & Eclipse) path into environmental- variable and run npm install -g cordova than generate apk file run ionic cordova build android

Comment: I try run to run the command ionic cordova build android and I getting this 

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

        ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
        JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
        Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android
        Studio,
        or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
        in your path, or install Android Studio

Comment: i think some problen in your android studio Gradle try this to solved 1)download gradle latest version bin file this link (https://gradle.org/releases/)
2)extract the winzip file into java folder (e.gC:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\gradle-3.5)
3)go to my computer right click -> properties.
4)then go to advanced system setting in left side menu.
5)advances -> environment Variables then select Path.
6)add new environment variable called %GRADLE_HOME%/bin

Comment: thank you for all the responds, I already solved the issue by manually installing the gradle and setting all the Environmental Variables properly.

Answer (score 0):

The Path as mentioned before is the correct path to find your generated apk file.

> yourProject/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-rele‌​ase-unsigned.apk

Please check these steps if there something missing.

**I. Development  environment  dependencies**

1)You need at Least to download a java JDK 8

2)Download an Android SDK manager

3)you must Add them to the environment variables

(Windows)

i)Open environment variables

ii)ANDROID_HOME:create a new user variable with name ANDROID_HOME and add the path of the SDK manager 
ex.C:\xxx\Android\sdk

iii)edit the user variable PATH value and add to it platform tools path ex. C:\xxx\Android\sdk\platform-tools

iV)JAVA_HOME:Don't forget also to edit in the user variable PATH, your old JAVA_HOME env path with the new JDK Path . ex.C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144

4)Globally install ionic and cordova

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

**II. Ionic CLI for build android**

5)`ionic cordova platform add android`

6)`ionic cordova build android`

**N.B:** there sometimes logging in issue through CLI when using this command, the next steps doesn't really make sense but it worked for me.

```
ionic config set backend pro -g
```

Retry the build process again ,if Still there a problem change to legacy and Then again back to pro

```
ionic config set backend legacy -g

ionic config set backend pro -g
```

It should work now, retry the build process again.

If still there a problem then make an app through the website of ionic
use this command with  the --pro-id  of your app and retry again.

```
ionic start --pro-id <ID>
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow this steps

1. Run `ionic cordova build --release android`
2. Open android studio go to Build -> Generate Signed APK, press next
3. If you don't have  Key store please create new one
4. Finish

you can find the APK under Platforms/android

Comment: thank you for the answer, what to do if I do not have Android Studio installed.

Comment: [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):    ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
        JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
        Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android
        Studio,
        or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
        in your path, or install Android Studio
I am getting that error message when I run the ionic cordova build android command.

Comment: for this approch you should have android studio, there is any season way you don't want to install android studio?, also see http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html

Comment: My device cant handle Android Studio that is why I choose Ionic Framework. Is there any other way I can solve this problem?

Comment: this may help you http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html

Comment: I already solved the issue, I manually installed the gradle and set all the Environmental Variables properly.